# Operator overloading definition outside of the class - C++

Tags: c++, class, overloading

Sorry this is such a simple question. I've been using tutorialspoint.com to learn C++. Currently I'm trying to learn about classes and operator overloading. For other member function, the website uses this convention

```
    class Box {
     private:
      int Volume;
     public:
      Box(int num);
      ...
     }
     Box::Box(int num) {
      Volume = num;
     }
```

However, when overloading operators, they use this

```
     class Box {
      private:
       int volume;
      public:
       Box(int num);
       Box operator+(const Box &b) {
        Box box;
        box.volume = this->volume + b.volume;
        return box;
       }
      }
```

They define the overloading function inside the class. Is it possible to define it outside the class? If so, how? I've tried

```
     Box Box::operator+(const Box &b) {...}
     Box::Box operator+(const Box &b) {...}
```

But these don't work

How do I do this outside of a class?

Again, sorry this is such a simple question.
Thanks

**EDIT**
My code looks like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Box {
 private:
  int volume;
 public:
  Box(int num);
  Box operator+(const Box &b);
};

Box::Box(int num) {
 volume = num;
}

Box Box::operator+(const Box &b) {
 Box box;
 box.volume = this->volume + b.volume;
 return box;
}

int main() {
 Box one(2);
 Box two;
 two = one + one;  
}
```

My error is

```
    Overloading.cc: In member function 'Box Box::operator+(const Box&)':
    Overloading.cc:18:6: error: no matching function for call to 'Box::Box()'
    Overloading.cc:18:6: note: candidates are:
    Overloading.cc:13:1: note: Box::Box(int)
    Overloading.cc:13:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
    Overloading.cc:5:7: note: Box::Box(const Box&)
    Overloading.cc:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
    Overloading.cc: In function 'int main()':
    Overloading.cc:25:6: error: no matching function for call to 'Box::Box()'
    Overloading.cc:25:6: note: candidates are:
    Overloading.cc:13:1: note: Box::Box(int)
    Overloading.cc:13:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
    Overloading.cc:5:7: note: Box::Box(const Box&)
    Overloading.cc:5:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: The 1st one should be fine. What do you mean "don't work"? Any error message?

Comment: When you say "these don't work", what do you mean by that? Do you get build errors? Unexpected results? Something else? Please elaborate, and give us more details (including build errors if you have them).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible, and common, to define operators outside of the class whenever possible.
You want this:

```
Box operator+( const Box& left, const Box& right ) { ... }
```

**Edit:**

If you mean you want to declare the operator as a member function and define it elsewhere (in the cpp) then it is:

h

```
class Box
{
    Box operator+( const Box& other ) const;
};
```

cpp

```
Box Box::operator+( const Box& other ) const { ... }
```

**Edit 2:**
Now that you've posted your error.  You are attempting to use a default constructor when you create `Box two;`  However, since you created a non-default constructor `Box( int )` the compiler is not generating a default constructor for you.

Comment: I think OP mean "member function".

Comment: Thanks. I thought that if a default constructor wasn't defined, the compiler sets the member variables to their default values on its own. e.g. all ints are defaulted to 0, all pointers to NULL, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The error message has nothing to do with operator overloading, it just complains `Box` doesn't have a default constuctor (i.e. `Box::Box()`) for the statement `Box box;` and `Box two;`.

You might add a default constructor for it, such as:

```
class Box {
 private:
  int volume;
 public:
  Box() : volume(0) {}
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  Box(int num);
  Box operator+(const Box &b);
};
```

or change the statement to specify the argument, such as:

```
Box box(0);
```